# geocoding rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, geocoding, geokit

I am trying to geocode multiple addresses in a model using either geokit or geocoder and I can't get either on of the gems to work as I want them to. Here is the code that I am applying to my model for both use cases and the errors I get for each option.

The Geocoder gist:
https://gist.github.com/112cc28b7d52402079ad

The Geokit gist
https://gist.github.com/adef30cb458c1177df2b

I am using devise, and rails 3.1 if that helps, and I am fairly certain that I am close to the correct code in the geocoder option, but don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails geocoder gem issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510734/rails-geocoder-gem-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined my own custom geocoding method similar to this:

```
def custom_geocode
   var = Geocoder.coordinates(self.address1)
   var2 = Geocoder.coordinates(self.address2)
   self.latitude1 = var.first
   self.longitude1 = var.last
   self.latitude2 = var2.first
   self.longitude2 = var2.last
end
```

Geocoder.coordinates returns an array of the latitude and longitude from the resulting address, and you save the resulting latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 0):

dont know geocoder, but i entered your shipping_address on [this demo site](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) for geocoder and it seems the response is an array. Your error message says that you're calling the latitude method on an array and ruby is angry about it. try using this instead :

```
start_result[0].latitude
```

Comment: I ended up defining a new method, I will post how I was able to do this when I have a little more down time.