# Geocoding multiple addresses in one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am trying to geocode 2 addresses in a model using geocoder and I can't get gem to work as I want to. Here is the code that I am applying to my model:

```
class Sender < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :source_address
validates_presence_of :destination_address
geocoded_by :source_address, :latitude => :latitude1, :longitude => :longitude1
geocoded_by :destination_address, :latitude2 => :latitude2, :longitude2 => :longitude2

def update_coordinates
    geocode
    [latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2]
end

after_validation :geocode
```

Here is code for views/senders/show.html.erb:

```
 <%= @sender.latitude1 %>
   <%= @sender.longitude1 %>
   <%= @sender.latitude2 %>
   <%= @sender.longitude2 %>
```

Result : 35.6894875 139.6917064 - Isn't it supposed to send me back 2 address information?

Here is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var source = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @sender.latitude1 %>, <%= @sender.longitude1 %>);
  var dest = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @sender.latitude2 %>, <%= @sender.longitude2 %>);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: source,
    zoom: 8

  }
  var mapOptions2 = {
    center: dest,
    zoom: 8

  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'), mapOptions2);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:source,
    map: map
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:dest,
    map: map2
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Does your `latitude, longitude, latitude2, longitude2` return 4 different values?

Comment: returns only latitude, longitude values which is shown in the result. Seems like geocoded_by :destination_address, :latitude2 => :lat, :longitude2 => :lon is not really working..

Comment: I think if you want `Geocoding multiple addresses` it need to return a `JsonArray` of geocoding address, and parse that, refer to [here](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem and solution are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482230/geocoder-to-work-with-two-addresses).

Add the following `before_save` and corresponding method to your model to solve the problem. Don't forget to repeat the part of code for the second location (maybe destination):

```
before_save :geocode_endpoints

  private
  #To enable Geocoder to works with multiple locations
  def geocode_endpoints
    if from_changed?
      geocoded = Geocoder.search(loc1).first
      if geocoded
        self.latitude = geocoded.latitude
        self.longitude = geocoded.longitude
      end
    end
    # Repeat for destination
        if to_changed?
      geocoded = Geocoder.search(loc2).first
      if geocoded
        self.latitude2 = geocoded.latitude
        self.longitude2 = geocoded.longitude
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

```
def function
...
end
```

as:

```
def update_coordinates
  geocode
  [latitude, longitude, latitude2, longitude2]
end
```

And also:

```
geocoded_by :destination_address, :latitude => :latitude2, :longitude => :longitude2
```

You also don't need `:latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lon` here:

```
geocoded_by :source_address, ...
```

And finally, coordinates are fetched automatically after record is validated. So you could do without `update_coordinates` (or `function`, in your version) and arrange the view for show action like this:

```
<%= @sender.latitude %>
<%= @sender.longitude %>
<%= @sender.latitude2 %>
<%= @sender.longitude2 %>
```

Comment: Thanks! give me back [35.6894875, 139.6917064, nil, nil]. Do you know why the latter 2 are empty?

Comment: When I follow your updated answer, it gives me back [ nil, nil, 35.6894875, 139.6917064]. I'm confused

Comment: Have you updated your question? Then you'll certainly need this: `geocoded_by :source_address, :latitude => :latitude1, :longitude => :longitude1` and correct this `geocoded_by :destination_address, :latitude => :latitude2, :longitude => :longitude2`

Comment: when I inspect element it shows me and error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , 
and below it's:  
var source = new google.maps.LatLng(, );
  var dest = new google.maps.LatLng(43.653226, -79.3831843);

Comment: The syntax seems to be correct. I guess geocoder can't resolve the source address coordinates for some reason. Try to increase timeout in config/initializers/geocoder.rb