# Multiple Coordinates in geocoder gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I am using the geocoder gem for the first time in my rails app. My question is little generic. My rails app need to submit from and to address.
When I look at the documentation provided in the [github](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) page, 
we have something like

```
rails generate migration AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToModel latitude:float longitude:float
rake db:migrate
```

Say supposing, my model name is **Location** which has **two address fields**:
**from_address** and **to_address** then should I have latitudes and longitudes separately for from and to address? if I set `geo_code` to both of these from and to addresses. i.e., something like

**In my Location model**

```
geocoded_by :from_address,:to_address
```

---

And,

**Model : Location**

```
Location(from_address: string, to_address:string, from_address_latitude: float, to_address_longitude: float, to_address_latitude: float, to_address_longitude: float)
```

So in short, should I have a separate latitude and longitude fields for both of these address fields`(i.e., from_address and to_address)` or is it simply enough to have just latitude and longitude?

Comment: Checkout the solution proposed in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655702/geocoding-multiple-addresses-in-one-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655702/geocoding-multiple-addresses-in-one-model) It works like magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define latitude and longitude for both addresses, then the following should work:

```
geocoded_by :from_address,
  latitude: :from_address_latitude,
  longitude: :from_address_longitude

geocoded_by :to_address,
  latitude: :to_address_latitude,
  longitude: :to_address_longitude
```

Comment: Could not get this solution working, basically the second `geocoded_by` call just overrides the first one. Reading the gem code, I can't find anything where it can actually adapt to two sets of addresses.

The solution I usually implement when facing this problem is to have a `Location` model:

```bash
rails g model Location address latitude:float longitude:float
```

And then have a `has_one :from_location, class_name: 'Location'` in my other model.